# How to reuse connection class instance?

Tags: java, reusability

Class `Openfire` contains a `connect` method that connects a user to the server. This method is called at the beginning when the user starts the application.

```
public class Openfire {

  private static Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(Constants.openfireIP);

  public boolean connect(String username,String password) {

    try {
        Openfire.connection.connect();
        Openfire.connection.login(username,password);
    }catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
   }

  public static Connection getConnectionInstance() {
      return connection;
  }
}
```

There are various places in the application where I will need the `Connection` instance. I want to reuse this, so that I don't again need to call the `connect` method.

Both the calls `connection.connect` and `connection.login` return nothing.

I created a method that returns me the connection instance but I do not understand what am I doing. Will just returning the instance solve the purpose ? I mean, can I continue without calling the `connect` method again *(from another class)* ?

Comment: What type of application is it? swing or web app?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to include in your static method the connect() and the login() calls to appropriate methods:

```
public static Connection getConnectionInstance(String username, String password) {

  boolean isOk = connect(username,password); 

  return connection;

}
```

In order not to connect every time you need to save your connection object in memory so you don't create every now and then a connection.

For example if in your main frame you create this connection using:

```
Connection con = Openfire.getConnectionInstance(username,password);
```

And you want to use this connection in another frame, or in another method in a class, you can pass this `con` Object to that Class (frame, method etc) and reuse it there, without the need to create a new Connection Object

Comment: So I have to connect every time ! This will make the app slow on several occasions

Comment: `Connection` class doesn't implement `serializable` interface.What do I do know ?